# How to use google speech recognition api in python?

Tags: python, google-api, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I have an mp3 file and I want to use Google's speech recognition to get the text out of that file. Any ideas where I can find documentation or examples will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad and a request for off-site resources which is off topic for Stack Overflow.  The only reason it hasn't been closed yet is due to the bounty attached.

Comment: I think you want to take a look at this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/speech

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Take a look at [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/) that enables developers to convert audio to text [...] The API recognizes over 80 languages and variants [...]
You can create a free account to get a limited amount of API request.

HOW TO:

You need first to install [gcloud python module](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/#/) & [google-api-python-client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation) module with:

```
pip install --upgrade gcloud
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Then in the Cloud Platform Console, go to the Projects page and select or create a new project. After you need to enable billing for your project, then [enable Cloud Speech API](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=speech.googleapis.com).

After enabling the Google Cloud Speech API, click the Go to Credentials button to set up your Cloud Speech API credentials

See [Set Up a Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/common/auth#set_up_a_service_account) for information on how to authorize to the Cloud Speech API service from your code

You should obtain both a service account key file (in JSON) and a GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable that will allow you to authenticate to the Speech API

Once all done, [download the audio raw file](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/samples/audio.raw) from google and also the [speech-discovery_google_rest_v1.json](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/samples/speech-discovery_google_rest_v1.json) from google

Modify previous downloaded JSON file to set your credentials key
then make sure that you have set your the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to the full path of the .json file with:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service_account_file.json
```

also

Make sure that you have set your GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variable to the ID of your Google Cloud project with :

```
export GCLOUD_PROJECT=your-project-id
```

**assuming all done**, you can create a ***tutorial.py*** file which contain:

```
import argparse
import base64
import json

from googleapiclient import discovery
import httplib2
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials


DISCOVERY_URL = ('https://{api}.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?'
                 'version={apiVersion}')


def get_speech_service():
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().create_scoped(
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
    http = httplib2.Http()
    credentials.authorize(http)

    return discovery.build(
        'speech', 'v1beta1', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URL)


def main(speech_file):
    """Transcribe the given audio file.

    Args:
        speech_file: the name of the audio file.
    """
    with open(speech_file, 'rb') as speech:
        speech_content = base64.b64encode(speech.read())

    service = get_speech_service()
    service_request = service.speech().syncrecognize(
        body={
            'config': {
                'encoding': 'LINEAR16',  # raw 16-bit signed LE samples
                'sampleRate': 16000,  # 16 khz
                'languageCode': 'en-US',  # a BCP-47 language tag
            },
            'audio': {
                'content': speech_content.decode('UTF-8')
                }
            })
    response = service_request.execute()
    print(json.dumps(response))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'speech_file', help='Full path of audio file to be recognized')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.speech_file)
```

Then run:

```
python tutorial.py audio.raw
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/ for documentation

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/samples/speech-discovery_google_rest_v1.json is now a broken link (404)

Comment: Exact, thanks you. You may still found a version here : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/revmischa/google-transcriber/master/speech-discovery_google_rest_v1.json, but as "The Client Libraries are released as Alpha and will likely be changed in backward-incompatible ways. The client libraries are currently not recommended for production use.", this answer will be soon deprecated...