# google speech api Invalid recognition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I am trying to follow the example on google speech api found here

https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/getting-started

1) I created the follow json request file

```
{
    'config': {
          'encoding':'FLAC',
          'sampleRate': 16000,
          'languageCode': 'en-US'
    },
    'audio': {
         'uri':'gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac'
    }
}
```

2) Authenticate to my service account

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=service-account-key-file
```

3) Obtain my authorization token successfully

```
gcloud auth print-access-token
access_token
```

4) Then use the following curl command

```
curl -s -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer access_token" \
    https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:syncrecognize \
    -d @sync-request.json
```

But I keep getting the following response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding..",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Do I need access permissions for the uri `gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac`? Is that what the problem is?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I just got exact same issue trying my first test.  I was using the cygwin64 version of CURL on Windows 10.  Sounds to me like it cannot interpret the json file.  I tried saving it as Unicode, but that's gave what I thought was a worse error.

Comment: You might also try taking off the -s for "Silent".  If like me, you will see more errors that might be hints.  I'm still trying to figure it out too.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is a file format issue.

You have to send WAV file instead of FLAC ...

[ FLAC and MP3 format are not supported <=> need a file conversion (representing cost) on the server side ]

Convert your audio file to WAV (using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) or [avconv](https://libav.org/avconv.html)), then retry.

You may also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703853/how-to-use-google-speech-recognition-api-in-python/38788928#38788928) (to see a working example)

Comment: This was Google's .FLAC file provided in their own example; hopefully they provide something that works.

Comment: Sorry for my bad answer, may you please add/update your functional code (as example)

Comment: We were both running demo exactly as per the sample Google website, see URL posted by original question. The post I made in Google Group indicate that CURL as interpreting the contents of the file as CURL commands, and thus not really the JSON for the web service call.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to remove the space between "-d @", 
so change "-d @sync-request.json" to "-d@sync-request.json".

I got help here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-speech-discuss/bL_N5aJDG5A.  Apparently the file was being read and processed, but the parms were going to the "curl.exe" instead of being passed to the URL.

Comment: Trying to apply the solution without a space between the -d and @ without success: it seems not to make any difference.

Comment: I was using the CURL from CYGWIN: https://www.cygwin.com/. 
I couldn't find any doc on why the space mattered, but I was getting exact same error as you and the change allowed it to work.  Maybe there are variation in different CURL implementations?

Comment: There might also be a way to pass the JSON on the CURL command line, I didn't try that.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is quite late for an answer. However, it might help others so putting in your error.

The config that you are passing is actually incorrect. The attributes should be like:

```
{
  "config": {
  "encoding": "LINEAR16",
  "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
  "languageCode": "en-US",
  "maxAlternatives": 1,
  "profanityFilter": true,
  "enableWordTimeOffsets": false
},
  "uri": {
    "content":"<your uri>"
  }
}
```