# Google Cloud Speech API python code sample has possible bug

Tags: python, google-speech-api

I am working through the provided code snippets from the Google Speech API, [found here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/transcribe.py). The code should be enough to convert a .wav file into transcribed text.

The block of interest is here:

```
def transcribe_file(speech_file):
    """Transcribe the given audio file."""
    from google.cloud import speech
    speech_client = speech.Client()

    with io.open(speech_file, 'rb') as audio_file:
        content = audio_file.read()
        audio_sample = speech_client.sample(
            content=content,
            source_uri=None,
            encoding='LINEAR16',
            sample_rate_hertz=16000)

    alternatives = audio_sample.recognize('en-US')
    for alternative in alternatives:
        print('Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
```

First, I think perhaps the code is old, and `sample_rate_hertz=16000` had to be changed to `sample_rate=16000`.

After that, I got an error for this line:
`alternatives = audio_sample.recognize('en-US')`
which read
`AttributeError: 'Sample' object has no attribute 'recognize'`

I am curious about how to rectify this. I can't seem to find any documentation on this method. Maybe it needs to be replaced too.

Comment: Please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703853/how-to-use-google-speech-recognition-api-in-python/38788928#38788928), because there is a similar working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nead to read file as binary, then use `service.speech().syncrecognize` with a **body** argument (dict), which contain all required arguments like :

- encoding,
- samplerate
- language)

May you try something like:

```
with open(speech_file, 'rb') as speech:
    speech_content = base64.b64encode(speech.read())

service = get_speech_service()
service_request = service.speech().syncrecognize(
    body={
        'config': {
            'encoding': 'LINEAR16',  # raw 16-bit signed LE samples
            'sampleRate': 16000,  # 16 khz
            'languageCode': 'en-US',  # a BCP-47 language tag
        },
        'audio': {
            'content': speech_content.decode('UTF-8')
            }
        })
response = service_request.execute()
print(json.dumps(response))
```

Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703853/how-to-use-google-speech-recognition-api-in-python/38788928#38788928), because there is a similar working example.

Answer (score 1):

You use the github quickstart.py example, so i wonder that's not in sync with the Documentation [Google Cloud Speech API class sample](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/speech-sample.html?highlight=class%20sample). But it's still **BETA**.

Assuming `isinstance(audio_sample, <class Sample(object)>) == True`,
then `.recognize` in your

```
alternatives = audio_sample.recognize('en-US')
```

should be one of

```
async_recognize, streaming_recognize, sync_recognize
```