# Why Google Speech Recognition API returns a part of converted text of audio

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Google Speech Recognition doesn't work only for few seconds audio. So I split my audio file to chunks. This is the class of splitting audio.

```
class Split_audio():
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Constructor
        """
    def create_folder(self,audio):
        """
        Create folder for chunks
        """
        #name of the folder: exemple audio file's name = test.wav ==> folder's name = test
        pos=audio.get_nameAudioFile()
        pos=pos.rfind('.')
        folder=audio.get_nameAudioFile()[0:pos]
        #if folder exist overwrite
        if os.path.exists(folder):
            shutil.rmtree(folder)
        #create folder
        os.makedirs(folder)
        return folder
    def split(self,audio,silence_thresh=None, min_silence_len=500):
        """
        Split audio file on silence
        """
        sound_file = AudioSegment.from_wav(audio.get_nameAudioFile())
        if silence_thresh==None:
            silence_thresh=int(sound_file.dBFS)-19
        audio_chunks = split_on_silence(sound_file, silence_thresh=silence_thresh, min_silence_len=min_silence_len)
        return audio_chunks
    def export(self,audio,path_folder=None):
        """
        Export chunks on wav's file
        """
        audio_chunks=self.split(audio)
        if path_folder==None:
            path_folder=self.create_folder(audio)
        for i, chunk in enumerate(audio_chunks):
            out_file = "chunk{0}.wav".format(i)
            path="%s/%s" %(path_folder,out_file) 
            chunk.export(path, format="wav")
```

I conclude that the quality of google_recognize output depends on silence_thresh and min_silence. After testing on 3 different audio I set the values ​​to silence_thresh=dbfs of the audio - 19 and min_silence=500ms. After 1 month I retested my code for the same audio. oops I had a transcript totally different from the first. 
here are the two results:
 [First result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgFBr.png) 
[second result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHEDO.png).
Any suggestion?

Comment: You can consider using google's api directly, not through the wrapper. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703853/how-to-use-google-speech-recognition-api-in-python#38788928

Comment: Note that speech recognition systems behind API's such as the one from Google will change their models regularly. Most of the time for the better, but for specific use cases, it might sometimes take a turn for the worse.